# Why does the implementation of pop_heap() function call another push_heap() function?

Tags: c++, stl

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Distance, class T>
void __adjust_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, Distance holeIndex,
                   Distance len, T value) {
  Distance topIndex = holeIndex;
  Distance secondChild = 2 * holeIndex + 2;
  while (secondChild < len) {
    if (*(first + secondChild) < *(first + (secondChild - 1)))
      secondChild--;
    *(first + holeIndex) = *(first + secondChild);
    holeIndex = secondChild;
    secondChild = 2 * (secondChild + 1);
  }
  if (secondChild == len) {
    *(first + holeIndex) = *(first + (secondChild - 1));
    holeIndex = secondChild - 1;
  }
  __push_heap(first, holeIndex, topIndex, value); **//why?**
}

template <class RandomAccessIterator, class T, class Distance>
inline void __pop_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                       RandomAccessIterator result, T value, Distance*) {
  *result = *first;
  __adjust_heap(first, Distance(0), Distance(last - first), value);
}

template <class RandomAccessIterator, class T>
inline void __pop_heap_aux(RandomAccessIterator first,
                           RandomAccessIterator last, T*) {
  __pop_heap(first, last - 1, last - 1, T(*(last - 1)), distance_type(first));
}

template <class RandomAccessIterator>
inline void pop_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last) {
  __pop_heap_aux(first, last, value_type(first));
}
```

from bottom to top, there are four function. the real operation to adjust heap is in __adjust_heap.

Now we review the code. After the **while** loop, there is a **if** block, which swaps the element at *holeIndex* and the element at *holeIndex*'s left child. And then call the __push_heap().

I think it is unnecessary to call __push_heap() function, if add an additional judgement in **if** statement, like this.

```
  if (secondChild == len && *(first + holeIndex) < *(first + (secondChild - 1))) {
    *(first + holeIndex) = *(first + (secondChild - 1));
    holeIndex = secondChild - 1;
  }
```

I provide my reasoning behind my assertion.

While the program run to the **if** statement, element at *secondChild* must be greater than *len*'s or equal to *len*'s . It means *secondChild* has no right child and maybe have a left child.So, *secondChild* must be the last non-leaf node on the max_heap, and its left-child must be a leaf node(if exists). It only needs to compare the *secondChild*'s element and its left-child's element. Left-child's element must be less than the element of *secondChild*'s parent, so, I think it is unnecessary to call __push_heap() to percolate up.

It is hard to describe my idea properly because of my poor English... >_

Comment: Why do people index structures this way? `*(first + secondChild)`  Why don't folks use syntax like `first[secondChild]`?

Comment: Identifiers with a double underscore are reserved.

Comment: My style comments aside, can you provide some reasoning behind your assertion?  You could _test_ your assertion by implementing both versions and validating that both update the heap equivalently.

Comment: @n.m. : I think they're asking about an implementation in a library.  Google sends me to this, but I imagine it's copied into other implementations:  http://root.cern.ch/svn/cint/trunk/stl/heap.h